# Cron job ignores executing docker command in python script

Tags: python, bash, docker, cron

I have a python script which pulls recent changes from gitlab repo and rebuild containers if something changed in repo. To automate this I use cron job, which triggers .sh script and inside this .sh script I try to execute python script. Cron job looks like this: `* * * * * /home/user_name/job.sh` . Sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export DISPLAY=:0
cd path_to_script
python3 gitpull.py
```

Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import git
import pymongo
import subprocess

url = 'mongodb://host:27017/'
client = pymongo.MongoClient(url)
db = client['branch']

def rebuild_command(service_name):
    f = open("/var/log/test_py_job.log","w")
    subprocess.call(f"docker-compose up -d --no-deps --build {service_name}", shell=True,stdout=f)

def git_pull(path,collection_name):
    collection = db[collection_name]
    repo = git.Repo(path)
    pullc = repo.remotes.origin
    pullc.pull('branch')
    current_head = str(repo.head.commit)
    last_saved_head = ''
    for sha in collection.find({},{"last_head":1, "_id":0}):
            last_saved_head = sha['last_head']
    if current_head == last_saved_head:
        return False
    else:
        collection.delete_one({'last_head': last_saved_head})
        collection.insert_one({'last_head': current_head})
        if path == './path':
            rebuild_command('frontend')


git_pull('./path','collection_name')
```

The problem is in following: If I disable cron job and execute python script manually everything works fine, but if I enable cron job executes only gitpull() function, docker command in rebuild() function doesn't execute. I made both files (job.sh, python script) executable with `chmod` command, docker runs without user privileges.

Comment: create your cron as `./run.sh &> out.log` , This will redirect stdout and stderr which might help you to figure out the issue. Most probably it is missing some path or environment variables which is getting set in bashrc.

Comment: What about the entries in test_py_job.log?? You should close the logfile using `with open("/var/log/test_py_job.log","w") as f: ...`